# Running multiple image manipulations in parallel causing OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, out-of-memory

I am working on a site where I need to be able to split and image around 4000x6000 into 4 parts (amongst many other tasks) and I need this to be as quick as possible for multiple users.

My current code for doing this is

```
var bitmaps = new RenderTargetBitmap[elements.Length];

using (var stream = blobService.Stream(key))
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.StreamSource = stream;
    bi.EndInit();

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {
        var element = elements[i];

        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        TranslateTransform translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        translateTransform.X = -element.Left;
        translateTransform.Y = -element.Top;
        transformGroup.Children.Add(translateTransform);

        DrawingVisual vis = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext cont = vis.RenderOpen();
        cont.PushTransform(transformGroup);
        cont.DrawImage(bi, new Rect(new Size(bi.PixelWidth, bi.PixelHeight)));
        cont.Close();

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(element.Width, element.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
        rtb.Render(vis);
        bitmaps[i] = rtb;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < bitmaps.Length; i++)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmaps[i]));
        encoder.Save(ms);
        var regionKey = WebPath.Variant(key, elements[i].Id);
        saveBlobService.Save("image/png", regionKey, ms);
    }
}
```

I am running multiple threads which take jobs off a queue. I am finding that if this part of code is hit by 4 threads at once I get an OutOfMemory exception. I can stop this happening by wrapping all the code above in a `lock(obj)` but this isn't ideal. I have tried wrapping just the first using block (where the file is read from disk and split) but I still get the out of memory exceptions (this part of the code executes quite quickly).

- I this normal considering the amount of memory this should be taking up?
- Are there any optimisations I could make?
- Can I increase the memory available?

UPDATE:

My new code as per Moozhe's help

```
public static void GenerateRegions(this IBlobService blobService, string key, Element[] elements)
{
    using (var stream = blobService.Stream(key))
    {
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.SourceRect = new Int32Rect(element.Left, element.Top, element.Width, element.Height);
            bi.StreamSource = stream;
            bi.EndInit();

            DrawingVisual vis = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext cont = vis.RenderOpen();
            cont.DrawImage(bi, new Rect(new Size(element.Width, element.Height)));
            cont.Close();

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(element.Width, element.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
            rtb.Render(vis);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
                encoder.Save(ms);
                var regionKey = WebPath.Variant(key, element.Id);
                blobService.Save("image/png", regionKey, ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your server? Maybe a retry and queue mechanism (eg. queueing up requests) can help here.

Comment: @ashes999 Is running on my local machine at the moment through iis express, my machine has 12gigs

Comment: Have you tried writing some test code that simply loads up 10 or more images on your machine to see if loading the images causes the issue at all?

Comment: @ananthonline nope, can give that a go

Comment: Whilst primarily concerned with resizing, you might want to look into http://imageresizing.net/ to see whether you can use it. At least take a look at the list of [pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/).

Comment: [I don't have enough rep to add comment so putting it here] If all else fails and since you say 4 threads cause an issue, you can use Semaphores to limit the number of accesses. Will be better than locks Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to call DrawImage of a 4000x6000 image in parallel, you're going to have a bad time.  You're cropping it too late, by the time you're rendering it to the RenderTargetBitmap it's already been rendered full size in memory.

Instead of cropping the image source with a transform, try to use the BitmapImage.SourceRect property like so:

BitmapImage.SourceRect = new Rect(element.Left, element.Top, element.Width, element.Height);

You may want to try putting that before you call BeginInit(), and get rid of the transform completely.

EDIT: Actually in your case you'd have to change the SourceRect in each iteration of the for loop.  And remember that you have to change the Size parameter in DrawImage to be the element size.

Comment: I like the sound of that, going to give a go now :)

Comment: Have updated my code and posted above, am finding the SourceRect doesn't seem to be effecting the output though, am getting the whole image returned resized into the different shapes?

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  Maybe try a CroppedBitmap instead of BitmapImage?  It should work with SourceRect.

Comment: ah got it, had to put it after BeginInit

Comment: So this solved the memory issue? Do you have any automated performance test where you make threads and try to concurrently crop 10, 100, 1000 images?

Comment: There will still be a threshold for running out of memory.  We've just raised the ceiling by a lot.  As long as it suits his real world application needs that's what matters.  Otherwise he could always do them in chunks.  For example, if he can only do 10 simultaneous operations without running out of memory, he would do 10 at a time and wait till the first 10 are done before doing another 10.